# JS IF statement to apply CSS to hide text if found on page

Tags: javascript, css, string, if-statement

Looking to hide specific text when/if it happens to get populated on a page. Unsure of how to do this

```
var str = "Lease from 0%* or 0%*";
  if( str.search("e") > 0) { 
  //apply css to hide the above string if found on page
}
```

Comment: So how are the strings demarcated? Are they contained within an element? Does it mean if the entire string contains one or more `e` it will be hidden/removed?

Comment: what do you mean by _hide that string_ ? it wold be inside some HTML markup. No ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) to get all of the textNodes, then iterate through them and remove the text from the nodeValue.  This will keep the text in non textNodes in place (you can replace `e` and your `<section>` tag won't get messed up, and if you have `<div class="entity">` or something, the className will remain as well:

```js
function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  return a;
}

let nodes = textNodesUnder(document.body);
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].nodeValue = nodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/test/g, '');
}
```

```css
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>This is a test</div>
    <span class="test">This is another test</span>
</body>
```

To do it on any dom change, you could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and do something like this (where I am setting the style to `color: red`, but you would set it to `display: none`:

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
let nodes = replaceTextUnder(document.body);
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  observer.disconnect();
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     mutation.addedNodes.forEach(n => replaceTextUnder(n))
  });
  observer.observe(document.body, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true  
   });
});

function replaceTextUnder(el){
  var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let index = a[i].nodeValue.indexOf('test');
    if (index !== -1) {
        let newNode = a[i].splitText(index);
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = 'red';
        span.appendChild(newNode);
        a[i].parentNode.insertBefore(span, a[i].nextSibling);
    }
  }
}



    
observer.observe(document.body, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true  
 });
 
 let div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = 'this is another test!';
 document.querySelector('.test').appendChild(div);
```

```html
<body>
        <div>This is a test</div>
        <span class="test">This is another test</span>
    </body>
```